# Using the Cosine Integration Recursion Formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I hope this is the type of question I can ask here:
I was given the following problem and told to use the recursion formula on it: $$\int x^2\cos(x)\ dx$$
The recursion formula I used was: $$\int x^n\cos(ax) \ dx =\frac 1ax^n\sin(ax)-\frac n{a^2}\int x^{n-1}\sin(ax) \ dx$$
I plugged it in once and got: $$ x^2\sin(x)- 2\int x\sin(x) \ dx $$
Now, to solve the $\int x\sin(x) \ dx $ part of my problem, I plugged it in to this recursion formula: $$\int x^n\sin(ax) \ dx = -\frac 1ax^n\cos(ax)+\frac n{a^2} \int x^{n-1}\cos(ax)\ dx$$
This got me: $$\int x\sin(x)\ dx = -x\cos(x)+\int \cos(x)$$
The anti-derivative of $\cos(x)$ is $\sin x$. My final solution was: $$x^2\sin(x)+2x\cos x-2\sin x +C $$
This answer seems right to me, but I'm not sure I am using the formulas the correct way. Was this problem done correctly?

Comment: Yes. Your work is correct. However, I would note that it may be easier to just integrate $\int x\sin(x)dx$ by parts instead of using the recursion formula.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: The process is explained in great detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Polynomials_and_trigonometric_functions. There is an example of integrating $x\cos(x)$ by parts on the page; the process for integrating $x\sin(x)$ is identical as in this example. I do want to stress however that your work is correct and integrating $x^2\cos(x)$ via reduction formulas is perfectly valid.

Comment: It's usually easy to check an integration:  Differentiate your answer.  Sometimes there's a trig identity or some algebra to do to make the derivative look like the integrand, but still, it's an easy check.